# Como estilizar componentes filhos através dos pais e componentes já criados pelo @material-ui

Tags: javascript, react

Estou criando uma sidebar e estou utilizando o `Drawer` do @material-ui e segui o primeiro `source-code` deste link (https://material-ui.com/pt/components/drawers/):

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Drawer from '@material-ui/core/Drawer';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import List from '@material-ui/core/List';
import ListItem from '@material-ui/core/ListItem';
import ListItemIcon from '@material-ui/core/ListItemIcon';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import InboxIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MoveToInbox';
import MailIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Mail';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  list: {
    width: 250,
  },
  fullList: {
    width: 'auto',
  },
});

export default function TemporaryDrawer() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    left: false
  });

  const toggleDrawer = (side, open) => event => {
    if (event.type === 'keydown' && (event.key === 'Tab' || event.key === 'Shift')) {
      return;
    }

    setState({ ...state, [side]: open });
  };

  const sideList = side => (
    <div
      className={classes.list}
      role="presentation"
      onClick={toggleDrawer(side, false)}
      onKeyDown={toggleDrawer(side, false)}
    >
      <List>
        {['Inbox', 'Starred', 'Send email', 'Drafts'].map((text, index) => (
          <ListItem>
            <ListItemIcon> <InboxIcon /> </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={'Inbox'} />
          </ListItem>

          <ListItem>
            <ListItemIcon> <MailIcon /> </ListItemIcon>
            <ListItemText primary={'Mail'} />
          </ListItem>
        ))}
      </List>
    </div>
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Button onClick={toggleDrawer('left', true)}>Open Left</Button>
      <Drawer open={state.left} onClose={toggleDrawer('left', false)}>
        {sideList('left')}
      </Drawer>

    </div>
  );
}
```

O que eu gostaria de fazer é "empurrar" **apenas** os icones 5px para a esquerda, colocando um `margin-left: 5` no componente `<MailIcon />` daria certo, porém eu não gostaria de fazer isso de forma "fixa", eu gostaria de seguir o mesmo formato do css padrão (Caso seja possivel), algo assim:

```
.List .ListItem .Icon{
     margin-left: 5px
}
```

Para, assim, eu poder colocar o `margin-left: 5px` para empurrar todos os icones que estiverem dentro da `List` e dentro da `ListItem`, independente se exitir 1 icone ou 5 ou 100 e indepenente do nome do icone, seja `<MailIcon />`, seja `<InboxIcon/>` ou o icone que for.

Answer (score 0):

No próprio site do material UI, eles dão varios [exemplos](https://material-ui.com/pt/customization/components/) de como você pode estilizar seus compoenentes.

Uma maneira de alterar o "CSS" global dos componentes é assim:

```
const GlobalCss = withStyles({
    "@global": {
        ".MuiList-root .MuiListItem-root .MuiListItemIcon-root": {
           marginLeft: "5px"
        }
    }
})(() => null);
```

Depois dentro do codigo chama esse componente

```
<GlobalCss/>
```

Essa é apenas uma maneira de atingir esse resultado.